# watch a dsf video file

Tags: video

i got a video file with extension .dsf
from a cctv surveillance camera.

how i can watch it?
suggest some free software (any os)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Generally companies like Vicon will allow users to export video with a separate file extension than .avi. One such extension is the .ave extension that Avigilon uses. This allows users to zoom in and out of the video at a later time where as .avi does not allow this. Another reason to have a different extension is for court use. A company uses an algorithm to put a fingerprint on the video so that if it is edited they know and it can't be verified. Most of the time you need to download the player from the company that supports that extension such as Vicon.